# How to fix geolocation not working in Firefox snap (currently 119.0.1)?

Tags: firefox, snap, geolocation

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have the issue of geolocation not working in Firefox snap (currently 119.0.1). Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Enable location services in Ubuntu Settings → *Privacy*  → *Location Services*.
2. Check in Firefox *Settings* → *Privacy and security* → *Location* → *Settings...* permissions that the flag *Block new requests asking to access your location* is not enabled.
3. Navigate in Firefox to: https://mylocation.org/
4. Click *Browser Geolocation*.
5. Click *Start Test*. A popup will ask you to allow the request.

   - Expected behavior: you get your latitude and longitude coordinates.
   - Actual behavior: latitude and longitude show *Failed*.

Please note that the Chromium snap can get the location correctly on the same site.

Can someone please confirm or deny the same behavior in the Firefox snap? Is there any workaround to get it working in Firefox snap? I love snaps so I would prefer a solution with the snap version of Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem by changing in `about:config` the value of `geo.enabled` from *false* to *true*. I have no idea why it was *false*.

However, please note that Chromium snap returns the correct location while Firefox snap returns a location 30 Km away, probably based on the IP address, but I really don't understand why.